# naming ivars with underscore, what is the practical implication

Tags: ios4, xcode4

I have read all the posts i could find on stackoverflow and elsewhere about this. I understand that the purpose of the underscore convention is to distinguish between the use of the ivar itself and its property, but if one is careful with variable names, I'm not sure what the practical difference is. I have two questions.

Is there a place that I can not use the accessors and would **have** to use the _var?
In other words, is there a place where I can't use:
`self.var
[self var]
self.var=foo
[self setVar:foo]`

Second, could someone describe a situation where **not** using the underscore convention would get me into trouble, that the underscore convention would otherwise keep me out of?

I'm sorry if this question is answered elsewhere; I didn't find it or I didn't understand it!

Answer (score 0):

well, legit for some, not for others, you could do something like this

```
-(void) setAlive:(BOOL) isItOrNot {

    if(isItOrNot) {
        [self setHPs:self.characterClass.baseHPs];
        [self.army addCharacterWithKey:self.key];
    } else {
        [self setHPs:0];
        [self.army removeCharacterWithKey:self.key];
    }

    alive_=isItOrNot;

}

-(BOOL) alive {
    return alive_;
}
```

as an example ... if you do that for iVars that you retain, handle the condition where the parameter is equal to the current iVar carefully :)